# how to disaplay last inserted records at the top in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function listStudentData() {

    $list = Student::all()->sortByDesc("first_name");
    return Datatables::of($list)
                    ->make(true);

}
```

this is not working !!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use latest() on your queries:

```
$students = Student::latest()->get();
```